# Поиск записей в текстовой БД средствами PHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть бд такого типа:

```
Id:Спб:  
...
- Город: спб 
- Имя: тупак
- о себе: говнокодер
...
```

многоточие обязательно между записями (в примере - людьми).

Как сделать поиск, что бы выводило не строчку а целый фрагмент, который между многоточием (ID могут повторяться)

Comment: С прибытием на Стак

Comment: Советую выкинуть бд на файлах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если БД текстовая... А подразумевается, из Вашего сообщения, что она текстовая, то это делается регулярным выражением.

bd.txt

```
Id:Спб:
...
Город: спб
Имя: тупак
о себе: кодер
...

Id:Мск:
...
Город: мск
Имя: корней
о себе: девелопер
...

Id:Мск:
...
Город: мск
Имя: Семен
о себе: блогер
```

code.php

```
function file_read($file) {
    $buffer = "";

    if(is_file($file)) {
        $buffer .= file_get_contents($file);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

$file = file_read("bd.txt");

// Ищем по Id
function search_id($id, $var) {

    $res = "";

    if (preg_match_all('/Id[:]'.$id.'[:].\s\.\.\.(.+)\.\.\./isuU', $var, $arr)) {
        foreach($arr[1] as $key=>$value) {
            $res .= "Запись ".$key."<br />---".nl2br($value)."<hr />";
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

function show_all($var) {

    $res = "";

    if (preg_match_all('/Id[:](.+)[:].\s\.\.\.(.+)\.\.\./isuU', $var, $arr)) {
        foreach($arr[2] as $key=>$value) {
            $res .= "Запись ИД:".$arr[1][$key]."<br />---".nl2br($value)."<hr />";
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

# Пример ищем Id:Спб:
$searchSpb = search_id("Спб", $file);
echo $searchSpb;

# Пример ищем Id:Мск:
$searchMsk = search_id("Мск", $file);
echo $searchMsk;

# Пример: выводим все записи
echo show_all($file);
```

Comment: Получится слишком долго.

Comment: @ArchDemon а что бы Вы предложили?

Comment: Он показывает что записи есть, но поиск не производит!

Comment: Сейчас поправим :) (Больше не буду сонный отвечать на вопросы на Стаке)

Comment: Сложно? и можно ли побольше комментариев? а то я новичок)

Comment: @ИванМартюгов Я поправил ответ, расширив функционал. Надеюсь вам пригодится.

Comment: Производим поиск всех позиций (смещение от начала) совпадающего текста. Дальше от  каждой позиции вверх и вниз находим начало и конец записи соответственно. Потом каждый кусок проходим регуляркой, чтобы распарсить данные. Для автора, вашего решения более чем достаточно. Он и в нём то не разобрался, а оно не такое сложное.

Comment: @ArchDemon у меня была мысль закинуть в ответ ссылку на документацию по регулярным выражениям... ))