# Надо подкорректировать код и настроить его

Tags: php, веб-программирование

```
    <html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/searh.css">
<b>Поиск по базе:</b><br><form action="" method="post">
 <p>Введите город: <input type="text" name="na" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Поиск"/></p>
</form>


</html>
<?
$dr = $_POST['na'];
function file_read($file) {
    $buffer = "";

    if(is_file($file)) {
        $buffer .= file_get_contents($file);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

$file = file_read("peple.txt");

// Ищем по Id
function search_id($id, $var) {

    $res = "";

    if (preg_match_all('/Id[:]'.$id.'[:].\s\.\.\.(.+)\.\.\./isuU', $var, $arr)) {
        foreach($arr[1] as $key=>$value) {
            $res .= "Запись ".$key."<br />---".nl2br($value)."<hr />";
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

function show_all($var) {

    $res = "";

    if (preg_match_all('/Id[:](.+)[:].\s\.\.\.(.+)\.\.\./isuU', $var, $arr)) {
        foreach($arr[2] as $key=>$value) {
            $res .= "Запись ИД:".$arr[1][$key]."<br />---".nl2br($value)."<hr />";
        }
    }

    return $res;
}


$searchSpb = search_id("$dr", $file);
echo $searchSpb;

?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста настроить форму и код поиска.

Comment: Если надо пример бд приложу

Comment: да не надо, конечно, ничего, тут же все телепаты кругом. пример бд еще, пфф. да и проблему тут за версту видно, да, ну очевидно ведь правда, всем сразу все ясно, что не так и что надо настроить.

Comment: @ИванМартюгов Еще, если позволите совет для Вас: ознакомьтесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking и на всякий случай с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @alexRoosso, не нужно цитировать автора, ему и так приходит цитата.

Comment: @And о как... сервис :) На самом деле я не из-за уведомления, а скорее как обращение, что бы было бы очевидным, к кому я то или иное сообщение отсылаю.

Comment: @alexRoosso, это очевидно если вы не адресуете никому, значит ТС'у сообщения, так-как придет уведомление только ему.

Comment: Не видно содержимое файла, что там ищите, возможно есть способ сделать это безбоязненно.

Comment: @And У меня привычка всегда цитировать то к кому обращаюсь... И насчет содержимого файла: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969380/331743 смотрите тут.

Comment: @alexRoosso, привычка, не привычка, это уже означает, что вы сами-то и не читали справку, а уже тулите ее ТС'у. И да, - тут можно обойтись `explode` и разобрать по `Id:`.

Comment: @And В справке на этот счет нет упоминаний. Наверное потому что отмечу или не отмечу я ТС в сообщение он все равно получит одно уведомление. Думаю разработчики Стака просто не стали заострять внимания на "прыжках через обруч" с тем, что бы участники пользовались стаком как им удобней. А что про Ваши решения... Так что же вы не предложите свое?

Comment: @alexRoosso, [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @And и где там сказано, что нельзя/не стоит/не рекомендуется упомянуть ТС? А вдруг кто то другой из участников беседы, может решить, что сообщение не ТС, а ему отправлено (двусмысленность возникнуть может)... Вам конечно очень хочется быть правым, но увы... не в этот раз, видимо. Вы субъективны... И даже судя по кол-ву ценных советов от Вас, думаете, что это Ваша площадка.Но это общественное место. Моё поведение ни чему не противоречит, и никому (видимо кроме Вас) не мешает. А потому, я предпочту остаться "при своем" а Вас оставить "при Вашем". Удачи с добрыми делами...

Comment: @And что и требовалось доказать, судя по Вашему поведению. Видите, я был прав... Вы сами это подтвердили, за что Вам отдельная благодарность. Нет ничего приятней доказательств собственной правоты. :)

Comment: @alexRoosso, Сначала вы говорите что в справке этого нет, потом начинаются отмазки, хотя я не говорил что нельзя, я сказал не надо, ибо в справке не сказано, что цитируйте всех, а сказано `Автор сообщения всегда получает уведомления о новых комментариях....:` - это уже говорит о том, что автору не надо обращаться через `@` он и так увидит. Это говорит о том, что обращаясь к автору через `@` делает это избыточным. Равно сильно тому, что в языке программирования завершающая точка с запятой, может быть не одна к примеру `echo $a;;;;` и все прекрасно будет работать, но на самом деле это избыточно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Подкорректировал код и настроил его.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/searh.css">
</head>
<body>
<b>Поиск по базе:</b><br><form action="" method="post">
 <p>Введите город: <input type="text" name="na" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Поиск"/></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

function file_read($file) {
    $buffer = "";

    if(is_file($file)) {
        $buffer .= file_get_contents($file);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

$file = file_read("people.txt");

// Ищем по Id
function search_id($id, $var) {

    $res = "";

    if (preg_match_all('/Id[:]'.$id.'[:].\s\.\.\.(.+)\.\.\./isuU', $var, $arr)) {
        foreach($arr[1] as $key=>$value) {
            $res .= "Запись ".$key."<br />---".nl2br($value)."<hr />";
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

function show_all($var) {

    $res = "";

    if (preg_match_all('/Id[:](.+)[:].\s\.\.\.(.+)\.\.\./isuU', $var, $arr)) {
        foreach($arr[2] as $key=>$value) {
            $res .= "Запись ИД:".$arr[1][$key]."<br />---".nl2br($value)."<hr />";
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

if(isset($_POST['na'])) {
    $search = search_id($_POST['na'], $file);
    if($search != "") echo $search;
    else echo "Не найдено записей соответствующих поиску";
}
```